How can I install mongodb extension in php on MAC with i9
I am trying to install mongodb extension my php for using Laravel. My Mongdb is running on Docker my php is running on my MAC with intel i9. When I try to pecl install mongodb command it gives me error. The error:

Notice: tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory in
System.php on line 420
PHP Notice:  tempnam(): file created in the
system's temporary directory in
/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.3.7/share/php/pear/System.php on line 420
Notice: tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory in
/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.3.7/share/php/pear/System.php on line 420
Notice: tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory in
System.php on line 420
PHP Notice:  tempnam(): file created in the
system's temporary directory in
/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.3.7/share/php/pear/System.php on line 420
Notice: tempnam(): file created in the system's temporary directory in
/usr/local/Cellar/php/8.3.7/share/php/pear/System.php on line 420
ERROR: failed to mkdir
/private/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/scripts/autotools/libbson


Note: Only the very last line of this is an error. The rest are just notices - they didn't crash the installer
